# Why is data not received by Node.js through POST request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

So I have this functionality.
The client is sending data through jquery post function

```
$.post(currentURL + "/api/tables", newReservation,

  function(data) {

    if (data == true) {
      alert("Yay! You are officially booked!")
    }

    if (data == false) {
      alert("Sorry you are on the waitlist")
    }

    $('#reserve_name').val("");
    $('#reserve_phone').val("");
    $('#reserve_email').val("");
    $('#reserve_uniqueID').val("");

  });
```

Then Node.js is receiving it here

```
app.post("reserve/api/tables", function(req, res) {
  var newentry = req.body;

  console.log(newentry);

  entries.push(newentry);

  res.json(newentry);
});
```

However, `console.log` is giving me this error

> jquery.js:9631 POST http://localhost:8080/api/tables 404 (Not Found)

Comment: What is `reserve` in `app.post()`. You are not sending to `/reserve/api/tables`

Comment: I tried to use just api/tables. That doesn't work either. Tried to join current dirname with api/tables, and that didn't worki either

Comment: What is `currentURL`?

Comment: I think you need to add `reserve` while making a request from jQuery

Comment: Are you using Express.js or similar? Best to tag it if you are.

Comment: Yes I'm using Express.js

Comment: I took currentURL out of the equation to no avail

Answer (score 0):

Because you are doing the request to the url: http://localhost:8080/api/tables , but your server is waiting you at : "reserve/api/tables".

Try to target: http://localhost:8080/reserve/api/tables

Comment: We don't know what's in `currentURL`.

Comment: I took currentURL out of the equation to no avail

Answer (score 0):

your routing specifies a localhost:8080/reserve/api/tables,

remove the 'reserve' routing

Comment: We don't know what's in `currentURL`.

Comment: I took currentURL out of the equation to no avail

Answer (score 0):

You are missing leading slash in
`app.post("reserve/api/tables", function(req, res) {`
so it should be
`app.post("/reserve/api/tables", function(req, res) {`
or
`app.post("/api/tables", function(req, res) {`
as edited later